# Javascript Question: Sum of all odd numbers to 100

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find out the sum off all odd numbers from 1 to 100 using a for loop. Here is my code so far:

```js
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 1);
  sum += i;
}
console.log(sum);
```

I thought maybe using a while loop maybe the solution, but whenever I try it, I always get an infinite loop error. So I tried switching back to a for loop, but the answer does not come out right. I believe I am looping through each number instead of every odd number. Is my "if" condition not correct? Any help is appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: `if (i % 2 == 1) ;` is an if statement with an empty body. Remove the `;`.

Comment: why not start `for (let i=1; i<=100; i += 2) { sum+= i; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `;` just after your `if` statement, so the next line is not going to get executed.

Just removing the `;` should work:

```js
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 1)
    sum += i;
}
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Typo questions are of no value to future readers, and should be flagged and closed, not answered

Comment: that is good to know :) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use step 2

```js
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 1; i < 100; i+=2) {
  sum += i;
}
console.log(sum);
```